Cyclic linked list definition
I'm trying to create a cyclic linked list definition in Rust and came up with the following implementation:
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode>>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { next: None, val }
    }

    pub fn for_each<F>(&self, f: F) -> ()
    where
        F: Fn(i32),
    {
        f(self.val);
        while let Some(next) = &self.next {
            f(next.borrow_mut().val);
        }
    }
}

The problem is when running the following code I got panic error: already borrowed: BorrowMutError
fn main() {
    let lst = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ListNode::new(10)));
    let mut ref_mt = lst.borrow_mut();
    ref_mt.next = Some(lst.clone());
    lst.clone().borrow_mut().for_each(|val| println!("{}", val))
}

Is there a way to fix up the code to make it work with RefCell or RefCell is inherently not suitable for such case?

FYI cycles between Rcs will never be deallocated, it's recommended to use Weak to break cycles

Try adding a drop(ref_mt) before the call to for_each(), so that the runtime borrow is dropped. Also, you probably don't need borrow_mut() to invoke for_each(), which takes a shared reference, &self. And does for_each() even need unique/mut access? borrow() should be sufficient there as well. Finally, your for_each() looks like it never terminates. A cyclic list should remember the first element, and stop when it encounters it again.

@vallentin Not sure how that would apply to a singly-linked cyclic list, though. There has to be a strong rc somewhere in the mix, they can't all be weak, and the list only has a single next pointer.

@user4815162342 That's why it's an FYI, since the title and tags mentions cycles :)

@vallentin I get that, and I understood your FYI as recommending the use of Weak, which I'm genuinely curious how to do in this case. Can you elaborate?

Since you only need immutable access, just replace borrow_mut() with borrow().

@user4815162342 I wasn't implying that replacing Rc with Weak was a solution. It was purely an FYI in relation to cycling references. Since people using Rcs with cycling references, always come back asking "Why it my application allocating more and more memory over time?". Thus I just commented an FYI upfront :)

@user4815162342 Indeed, replacing mutable borrows with immutable onces does the job.

@vallentin I'm still curious how to apply that advice here. :)

@user4815162342 Here, you're welcome :) Like honestly, I don't know what else you want here, it was literally just an FYI, tiny bit of information, because 99% of the time, people will run into that "issue" next. Where them using cyclic references with Rc causes their application to consume more and more memory. Beyond that, I'm not going to entertain your attempt at a "gotcha" anymore. It was just a related note, based on OPs title and tags being "cyclic/circular references"

@vallentin You imply that I was somehow trying to trick you, but that's not the case. Weaks are indeed used to break cycles, and I was genuinely curious how to apply that to a cyclic list as defined here. It seems to me that it doesn't, but I could be mistaken.

@user4815162342 OP already mentioned their solution, but here, this version uses Option<Rc<...>>, notice how it never prints Dropped .... While this version uses Option<Weak<...>> and actually does print Dropped .... Whether either is a solution for OP, depends on context we don't have. The fact still remains, that the Weak version actually drops :)

@vallentin Right, but I believe the problem with that approach is that the list doesn't hold its own nodes, as the Weaks require strong references somewhere. That's not how linked lists normally work.

@user4815162342 Yes, I agree, that's why I said it depends on context we don't really have. Overall, having a linked list implementation that just continuously allocates more and more memory, as items are added is just pure bad. I'm saying this as someone who works with real-time high performance applications.

@vallentin Yeah, Weak here kind of throws away the baby with the bathwater. You get a cyclic linked list that doesn't leak at the price of it not holding onto anything. Normally using Weak (e.g. in doubly linked lists) doesn't come with such a tradeoff.

In (safe) Rust programs, data can have at most one mutable reference, which is governed by the ownership rules and enforced by the borrow checker. Wrapping a type with Rc doesn't change that as discussed here and is the reason for using the RefCell. It uses interior mutability to allow what on the surface looks like multiple mutable references. However, as discussed here, the same rules apply, they're just checked "dynamically" (i.e. at runtime, not at compile time). That is the problem you've hit here. There was a point in time at which the “aliasing XOR mutability” rule was violated.
Let's see where things go wrong.
First, ref_mt is still in scope (mutable borrow 1) when there's an attempt to call for_each (mutable borrow 2). Let's fix that by explicitly dropping ref_mt.
let mut ref_mt = lst.borrow_mut();
ref_mt.next = Some(lst.clone());
drop(ref_mt);
lst.clone().borrow_mut().for_each(|val| println!("{}", val))

With that change, at least "10" is printed once.
Next, the node remains borrowed when attempting to iterate, which itself will try to borrow the same node. Let's fix that by avoiding the unnecessary mutable borrow.
lst.clone().borrow().for_each(|val| println!("{}", val))

Next, we run into the same problem in the infinite iteration. Let's fix that the same way.
f(next.borrow().val);

Finally, the cycle works and the program will continue printing "10" in a loop for as long as you let it.
Full version of the modified code:
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode>>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { next: None, val }
    }

    pub fn for_each<F>(&self, f: F) -> ()
    where
        F: Fn(i32),
    {
        f(self.val);
        while let Some(next) = &self.next {
            f(next.borrow().val);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lst = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ListNode::new(10)));
    let mut ref_mt = lst.borrow_mut();
    ref_mt.next = Some(lst.clone());
    drop(ref_mt);
    lst.clone().borrow().for_each(|val| println!("{}", val))
}


There's no need to have ref_mut holding a ref. Just do lst.borrow_mut().next = Some(lst.clone()); This also eliminates the need to use drop().

In any Rust program, safe or unsafe, data can have at most one mutable reference.

@Todd - I tried to change as little as possible about the code. I agree that removal of unnecessary variables is desirable. From a pedagogical standpoint, I think either works.

@ChayimFriedman - I don't think that's correct. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc9bc7880da7d4b0364df97802120cd2

Well, in unsafe Rust you can break the rules. That doesn't mean you are allowed to, just that now you have UB. Run it under Miri.

There was no claim that having multiple mutable reference is sound, just that is it possible. The point is that in unsafe Rust, data can have more than one mutable reference. Whereas in safe Rust, that's not possible as indicated in the answer.
